How to enable fix ESLint sort-keys rule in WebStorm?
I have ESLint rule
"sort-keys": ["warn", "asc", { "caseSensitive": false, "natural": true }]

WebStorm sees the error, but does not offer to fix it as it does with other rules. FixEslintProblems doesn't work also --fix command.
